# How to convert html to PDF on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I convert an `html` file to a PDF on Windows Phone 8.1? I checked `NReco` library but it does not work. I found only `sharpPDF` library to generate PDF but it is not a sufficient solution for me.

Comment: Why is it not a sufficient solution for you? Please check [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here on how to ask good questions on stack overflow.

Comment: SharpPDF is not working, because it has a compiletime dependency on System.Drawing.dll.